# no duplication of username does not work on my C# windows form, it only debugs the first array of my .txt file

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

Example .txt file output will be:

```
lastname|firstname|tintin|password|Manager
lastname|firstname|carley|password|Manager
```

If I try to register username 'tintin' and other data, it debugs it and says that the username already exists.
If I try to register username 'carley' and other data, the data is recorded in the .txt file even though there is already an existent carley username in the file. Please help.

```
private void btnregister2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fStream = new FileStream("UserAccount.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader fReader = new StreamReader(fStream);
    string fLine = fReader.ReadLine();
    string[] fContent = fLine.Split('|');
    if (fContent[2].Equals(txtusername2.Text))
    {
        fContent = fLine.Split('|');
        MessageBox.Show("username already exists!");
        fLine = fReader.ReadLine();
        fReader.Close();
        fStream.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        fReader.Close();
        fStream.Close();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtlastname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfirstname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbaccounttype.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR! There is an empty text.");
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter record = new StreamWriter("UserAccount.Txt", true))
            {
                record.WriteLine(txtlastname.Text + "|" + txtfirstname.Text + "|" + txtusername2.Text + "|" + txtpassword2.Text + "|" + cmbaccounttype.Text);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Account successfully registered!");
            cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the format of my streamwriter, i'm not sure if that's the problem. I'm expecting that there would be no duplicate in the data of the .txt file and what the user inputs.

Comment: You are reading only one line of the file. You need to use some kind of loop to read every line and check if the username matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

You only `read the first line of the file` and you have to `read and compare all the lines` using `while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`:

```
        bool _isUserExist = false;
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("UserAccount.txt"))
        {
            string s = String.Empty;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (s.Split('|')[2] == txtusername2.Text)
                {
                    _isUserExist = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("username already exists!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!_isUserExist)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtlastname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfirstname.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbaccounttype.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR! There is an empty text.");
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter record = new StreamWriter("UserAccount.Txt", true))
                {
                    record.WriteLine(txtlastname.Text + "|" + txtfirstname.Text + "|" + txtusername2.Text + "|" + txtpassword2.Text + "|" + cmbaccounttype.Text);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Account successfully registered!");
                cleanup();
            }
        }
```